# For any integer $n\ge0$ it follows that $9\mathrel|(4^{3n}+8)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility

I have been trying to use induction in order to prove the above statement but I always reach a dead end. How can this statement proven via induction?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you post what you've tried so we can help you get past the "dead end".

Comment: Sure. my bad. After observing that this statement is true for n=0 I continue to check if it is true for 9|(4^(3(n+1))+8). Then, 4^(3n+3)+8 = 4^(3n)*4^(3)+8 = (4^3) * (9c-8) + 8. From here on out I cant find a common factor 9 in order to reach a proof.

Comment: $4^{3n+3}+8=4^{3}(4^{3n}+8)-8\times4^3+8$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Find", "Show") to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post

Comment: @DonLarynx Do you mind if I copy your comment in order to paste it myself in situations like this? Your formulation exceeds mine.

Comment: @drhab: yes, copy.

Answer (score 1):

**Base case**: is this statement true for $n = 0$? That is, does $9$ divide $4^0 + 8$?

**Inductive step**: assume that $9$ divides $4^{3n} + 8$ and use this to check that $9$ also divides $4^{3(n + 1)} + 8$.

From here, your proof looks ok; if we assume $9$ divides $4^{3n} + 8$, then $4^{3n} + 8 = 9c$ as you note. Thus you can write

$$
4^{3(n + 1)} + 8 = 4^3 (9c - 8) + 8 = 64\cdot 9c - 8(64 - 1) = 64 \cdot 9c - 8\cdot 63
$$

do you see how to conclude?

Comment: I edited my comment. It includes the inductive step as well now.

Comment: ok, I've shown some steps past where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative proof** (without induction):

It is to be shown that $\overline{4^{3n}+8}=\overline{0}$ where
$\overline{r}:=r+9\mathbb{Z}\in\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$.

> $\overline{4^{3n}+8}=\left(\overline{4}^{3}\right)^{n}+\overline{8}=\overline{1}^{n}+\overline{8}=\overline{1}+\overline{8}=\overline{0}$